# Javascript - Login Box Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, variables, authentication, passwords

I am currently making a javascript and html mini-login box. I have created a javascript code which checks the length of the password and checks if confirm password and password are the same. Here is the code...

```css
<form name = "logme">
<fieldset>
<legend>Create Your Account!</legend>
<br>
<p>Username:*<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
<br> 
<br>
Password:*<input type="password" id="pass">
<br>
<p>Confirm Password:*<input type="password" id="passwd">
<br>
<p>Email:*<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com">
<br>
<br>
Show Password:<input id="chk" name="chk" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Create!" name="Submit" onclick="pwFunction()">
</p>
<a href="create.html">Don't Have An Account? Create One!</a>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

```html
<script>

function pwFunction() {
var password = document.getElementById('pass');
var lok = password.value.length >= 8;
var cpassword = document.getElementById('passwd');

 if (!lok) {
      alert('Your Password Must Have Eight Characters!');
    }
    return lok;

if(password.value != cpassword.value) {
  alert('Your Passwords Do Not Match!');
   }
 }
 
</script>
```

It Only Runs The 'Your Password Must Have Eight Characters' Alert.
Why Isn't It Running Both?
Thanks For Any Answers, And Sorry For The Inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of error in your code / scripts:

Edit 1. Change the button to

`<input type="submit" value="Create!" name="Submit" >`

Edit 2. Use javascript validation on form tag

```
<form name = "logme" action="somewhere" onsubmit = "return pwFunction();">
```

This way the form is submitted only when the pwFunction() returns true.

Edit 3. Your javascript function should be:

```js
function pwFunction() { 
var password = document.getElementById('pass');
var cpassword = document.getElementById('passwd');

 if (password.value.length < 8) {
      alert('Your Password Must Have Eight Characters!');
   return false;
    }

  if(password.value != cpassword.value) {
  alert('Your Passwords Do Not Match!');
    return false;
   }
  else
    {
      return true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you did, the `return` statement is executed always, so it causes the function to stop execution and return a result. delete the return statement:

```
if (!lok) {
  alert('Your Password Must Have Eight Characters!');
}

if(password.value != cpassword.value) {
   alert('Your Passwords Do Not Match!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(password.value !== cpassword.value) {
 alert('Your Passwords Do Not Match!');
}
```